# Why does my GitHub Pages URL return the wrong page in Chrome?

Tags: browser, github-pages

I've been playing around with GitHub pages for a while, and have been doing most of my development in Firefox. Everything was working amazingly, until I attempted to test my project page in Google Chrome. To my surprise, when visiting the same GitHub project page in Firefox and Chrome, Firefox was served the correct index.html page while Chrome was served a completely different (and incorrect) one.

I've poked around for a few hours now and honestly have no idea what's going on. Both Firefox and Chrome are requesting the exact same URL with an HTTP GET request and receive different responses from the server. I've tried changed the user agent and messing with the request header in both browsers, and it didn't seem to affect anything.

Does anybody have a clue what's going on? If it helps, the project page in question is "https://wgxli.github.io/complex-function-plotter/". Any help is much appreciated.

Edit: It appears to be related to a browser cache issue. The behavior disappears if I clear all data from the browser and visit the above page. However, if I clear the browsing data, visit the root directory of the above page, and then request the above page, the problem reproduces itself. At this point, I think I've reduced it to a question of why the browser (or CDN) is returning a cache hit when it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing the issue. I was using create-react-app, which automatically registers a service worker for local caching. I just disabled this service, which resolved the problem.